# How to buffer vector of structure of arrays using boost?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a structure that looks like:

```
typedef struct{
   float test_var[2]; 
}test;
```

Rest of the code:

```
std::vector<test> test_vector;
std::vector<float> float_vector;
```

Boost buffer function is used to serialize these vectors and send to python client.

```
std::array<boost::asio::const_buffer, 2u> seq = {
        boost::asio::buffer(test_vector),
        boost::asio::buffer(float_vector)}
```

After serialization, it is required to calculate start address of memory from where  `float_vector` data starts. 
I am using:

```
auto start = _data + (sizeof(test) * test_vector.size());
```

`_data` is the start address of buffered memory. But I get following error in python:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

The exact same code works well when structure is changed to :

```
typedef struct{
   float test_var; 
}test;
```

Is the problem with buffering vector of structure of array? or with the calculation of start?

**Additional info:**
Once buffered, the data is sent to C++ API module where serialized data is converted to python list type and linked to python API. So far only API is defined for converting `float_vector` to list which is why `start` is calculated. This works as mentioned when structure has no array.

```
.def("get_float_vector", &GetPyList<csd::testClass>)
```

Comment: What's the type of `_data`? A `char*`?

Comment: It is casted to uint8_t*